# Updating a button from 1 function in another using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am looking to update a button in my code by running a function later in the code that references a previous function, then update that said button with new text. When I run this code, it states that Source1 is not defined when the okay 3 function runs the if statement. New to coding and looking for tips. Thanks

```
from tkinter import *

import pandas as pd

##database = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Code/CODETEST.xlsx').parse(1)

excel_data_df = pd.read_excel('CODETEST.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

print(excel_data_df)

print(excel_data_df.columns.ravel())

##print(excel_data_df['Service Name'].tolist())


My_Service_List = (excel_data_df['Service Name'].tolist())

print(My_Service_List)

##Source1_Text = tk.StringVar()

root = Tk()

##Creating Entries
Group = Entry(root, width=50)
Group.grid(row=0, column=5)
Source = Entry(root, width=50)
Source.grid(row=1, column=5)
Service = Entry(root, width=50)
Service.grid(row=2, column=5)

global Source1
global Standard_window

def Standard_flow():
    ##global Source1_Text
    Standard_window = Tk()
    ##Source1_Text = tk.StringVar()
    ##Source1_Text.set("Original Text")
    Source1 = Button(Standard_window, text=My_Service_List[1])
    Source1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    Source2 = Button(Standard_window, text='HDA')
    Source2.grid(row=1, column=2)
    Source3 = Button(Standard_window, text='Router')
    Source3.grid(row=1, column=3)


# Definining Buttons
def Okay():
    hello = "Searching " + Group.get()
    myLabel = Label(root, text=hello)
    myLabel.grid(row=0, column=6)


def Okay2():
    hello2 = "Searching " + Source.get()
    myLabel2 = Label(root, text=hello2)
    myLabel2.grid(row=1, column=6)


def Okay3():
    hello3 = "Searching " + Service.get()
    myLabel3 = Label(root, text=hello3)
    myLabel3.grid(row=2, column=6)
    if My_Service_List.__contains__(Service.get()):
        Source1.config(text=My_Service_List[3])
        return Standard_flow()
    else:
        None


##Creating Buttons
myButton_Group = Button(root, text='Group Multicast IP', command=Okay)
myButton_Source = Button(root, text='Source IP', command=Okay2)
myButton_Service = Button(root, text='Service Name', command=Okay3)

##Displaying Buttons
myButton_Group.grid(row=0, column=1)
myButton_Source.grid(row=1, column=1)
myButton_Service.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please keep a mention of which button you want to edit and and the error you get

Comment: The button I want to edit is "Source1", you see in the if statement "Source1.config(update text)"

Error is.. 

"Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\206415779\Anaconda3\envs\FINDIT\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/206415779/Python/FINDIT/FINDIT START", line 66, in Okay3
    Source1.config(text=My_Service_List[3])
NameError: name 'Source1' is not defined"

Comment: try saying `global Source1` inside of `Standard_flow()` and not on the main block

Comment: `def Okay3():
    hello3 = "Searching " + Service.get()
    myLabel3 = Label(root, text=hello3)
    myLabel3.grid(row=2, column=6)
    if My_Service_List.__contains__(Service.get()):
        Source1.config(text=My_Service_List[3])
        return Standard_flow()`

Are you saying return Standard_flow(global Source1")?

Also I'm not sure I understand, the "not on the main block"?

Comment: no no ill add as an answer please wait

Comment: Really appreciate it, been racking my brain all day on this one. I've tried all sorts of global calls with no luck.

Comment: ive added an asnwer, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `Source1` is a local variable and hence it is available only to the function that you defined it on, that is, `Standard_flow()`. To make this global and fix the error, just try saying this:

```
def Standard_flow():
    global Source1
    Standard_window = Tk()
    ......
```

With this change, the error should go and it should work. And just keep this `global Source1` and remove all other `global Source1` in your code(i mean the one outside the function)

Do let me know, if the error persists

Cheers

Comment: Still no luck, I removed the global Source1 from above the Standard_flow function. I then added global Source1 to the Standard_flow. Still receive the same error when the if statement returns true. "NameError: name 'Source1' is not defined"

Comment: ive updated the Q with the whole code, take a look and let me know if its same to yours

Comment: Tried a copy paste and no go, same issue, I believe because it is a button and not a variable, will have to search tkinter I believe to figure out how to update a button.

Comment: this is the right way to update a button and im tearing my heads apart right now, this should work, something simple is being missed here :(

Comment: Hahaha well I'm glad to hear I was not that far off. I'm currently trying to define that button outside of the Standard_flow function, perhaps I need to declare that button prior to the Standard_flow function?

Comment: mmmm yes? try it out? all the best

Comment: I got it to work by defining Source1 prior to that function, but the problem is when the if statement is true and returns the Standard_flow function it shows the wrong text, when I click that button again I get the corrected updated text. do I have to return the new Source1 value prior to return Standard_flow?

Comment: yes? try it out, you will end up with the answer yourself :D

Comment: Once again didn't come back to give thanks. @CoolCloud, thank you for the help!

Comment: @Josh oh, means alot, Happy coding